# Grails control join table

Tags: grails, grails-orm

my alert entity has connection to these entites.. Can they all be joined into one big table? This is a one to many relationship. And not having alert_locations, alert_user,etc

```
class Alerts { 

    static hasMany = [locations:Locations, alertStatus:AlertStatus, users:Users]
    Date alertDateTime
    String pest
    String crop

    static constraints = {
        alertDateTime (blank:false)

        pest (blank:false)
        crop (blank:false)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make the relationships bidirectional with an `Alerts` field then it will eliminate the need for join tables since it can store the foreign key to the `Alerts` in each table, e.g.

```
class Locations {
   Alerts alerts
   ...
}
```

You can also use the map form of `belongsTo` which would add cascaded deletes:

```
class Locations {
   static belongsTo = [alerts: Alerts]
   ...
}
```