# Grails Join Table column name

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, join

My `Alert` has many `Location` objects, and I have the join table `alert_locations`.

The generated columns are:

`alerts_locations_id` (I want this to be `alert_id`)

`location_id`

Here's my domain object:

```
class Alerts { 

    static hasMany = [locations:Locations,notifications:Notifications]

    Date alertDateTime
    String pest
    String crop

    static constraints = {
        alertDateTime (blank:false)

        pest (blank:false)
        crop (blank:false)
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails control join table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897524/grails-control-join-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static mapping = {
    locations joinTable:[column:"location_id", key:"alert_id"]
```